# 4.0 ICS: Access safe mode without volume buttons

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet, safe-mode

My dad has a [GEM7008](http://www.geminidevices.com/7008.html) tablet running 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich and has managed to acquire the [Cheshire Police virus](http://guides.yoosecurity.com/computer-locked-by-cheshire-police-authority-virus/). Bear in mind that he's in his 60s and before getting this tablet, he'd never used a PC/Laptop/tablet/smartphone before. And I'm helping him over the phone.

The link above has instructions for removing this virus from tablets/phones and involves booting the phone into safe mode by turning the tablet off, then turning it on, and holding the volume buttons while it's turning on. The problem is, the tablet doesn't have any volume buttons. The route into safe mode for 4.1 doesn't work on his tablet, as expected.

How can I get into safe mode?

Comment: One thing you could try: with the device being running, long-press the power button. That should open the "power menu", which often offers to boot into different modes (including safe-mode). If that option is not present, I'm on a loss with further direct hints; though I remember a similar issue pointing out some "tricks" with the power key alone, I currently can't find it.